# Android: create a changeable module in xml

Tags: android, xml

Is it possible to create an xml module/structure that I can include in another xml with custom settings?

The idea is to make a module with a seekbar, a text and a text input. I will need this module about 20 times in another xml but its values (like the text and ids) are different for each instance.

Is there a way to do this in xml?

Or is there a way to make a class that uses this base xml module and lets me set the desired values via xml?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the merge and include tags in xml layouts.  For example in grid_layout_view.xml you have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">
    <include android:id="@+id/my_inside_grid_layout" 
             layout="@layout/grid_layout_inside"/>    </GridLayout>
```

Note the use of the  tag to import the contents of the grid_layout_inside.xml file which contains the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="fill">
    </ListView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Button
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:text="OK"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
     </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

Hop this helps,
Ruben

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. is it possible with this, for example, to include the grid_layout_inside.xml multiple times in grid_layout_view.xml and have be able to set a different text for the cancel button from grid_layout_view.xml for each <include>?